# Rest docs with Spring data Rest for Spring-data-couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-couchbase, spring-restdocs

Hi guys having a very rough day trying to figure out Restdocs with Spring Data Couchbase and Spring Data Rest.

Currently I have a Spring-Data-Couchbase Project leveraging spring-Data-Rest-Hal-Browser.  This is awesome because it basically overs a CRUD Couchbase repository with full Restful service Support.  I love the Hal Browser, however, I wanted to augment project with Spring Restdocs for additional documentation.

I am not concern with testing the base CRUD functionality provided, however, I want to leverage that test driven documentation approach to make sure the documentation is always up to date.  Is there a way to full mock out Couchbase or some sort of baseline in memory representation I can use to accomplish this?

If possible I would absolutely love a sample or reference documentation or .... well really anything that can help me at this point.  I have been stuck on this for almost a whole week now :(

Thanks a ton to anyone who can help!

I uploaded my current code to Github so anyone can get a clearer picture if needed:
https://github.com/Mandalorian007/couchbase-service-example/

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase cannot run in process, but there is a couchbase-mock project under the couchbaselabs github organization. Maybe that can suffice to your needs?

Comment: I will try it out.  Do you know if there is a way to completely mock out couchbase so there is no startup time?